# What causes BitBake worker processes to exit unexpectedly?

Tags: linux, docker, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have a BitBake build process that runs on a Docker container (CentOS 7).  The BitBake fails during `recipe gcc-cross-i586-5.2.0-r0: task do_compile` on each run that I try it in.

**An example of** `bitbake`**'s output:**

```
NOTE: recipe gcc-cross-i586-5.2.0-r0: task do_compile: Started
ERROR: Worker process (367) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Worker process (367) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Worker process (367) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
ERROR: Worker process (367) exited unexpectedly (-9), shutting down...
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1538 tasks of which 17 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
```

Is this a problem with `recipe gcc-cross-i586-5.2.0-r0: task do_compile`? Perhaps an out-of-memory error? I don't know what the `-9` refers to or how to find out more information about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ bitbake -c cleansstate gcc-cross ; bitbake -k gcc-cross
```

How much you have memory of ram?

Report log error here.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

Edit conf/local.conf and decrease the number of working threads by adding the following to you conf/local.conf file (under the build directory):

BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "6"

Answer (score 0):

Just a long shot, -9 in kernel land means EBADF (bad file number.)  Is it possible you have done some operations as root and some files are not accessible during the build?  Is the issue reproducible?  ie. can you rm -rf tmp and does it happen again?  Make sure you don't have any permissions issues in your project directory and associated file system(s).

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind. The problem is reproducible and happens during every build; the tmp directory is created from scratch every time.

Comment: 9 is signal nine, `SIGKILL`, which happens when a task takes too much memory (i.e. out of memory).